# Calling the public instance methods of a composed private class member without passthrough functions in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I am trying to find a way to avoid creating lots of passthrough methods on a class's prototype. I have a class ProgressBar, which has a lot of instance methods. I want to create a new class (called ComposedProgressBar in my code example), which "has a" progressBar instance, and does not inherit from ProgressBar.

In order to access the progressBar's instance methods from the client code, it would be customary to create a series of passthrough functions. Such as:

```
ComposedProgressBar.prototype.setWidth = function (width) {
    this.progressBar.setWidth(width);
};
```

However, I'm trying to avoid this.

I am able to access the progressBar's privileged methods by adding the following to the ComposedProgressBar's constructor:

```
ProgressBar.call(this);
```

But, this isn't suitable for what I'm trying to implement. I need access to the methods that have been added to ProgressBar's prototype.

Below is the example code based on what I'm currently working with. I have included the height setter and getter just to illustrate that using ProgressBar.call(this) works for them.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to achieve?

```
function ProgressBar() {
    "use strict";
    this.width = 0;
    this.height = 0;

    this.setHeight = function (height) {
        this.height = height;
    };

    this.getHeight = function () {
        return this.height;
    };
}

ProgressBar.prototype.setWidth = function (width) {
    "use strict";
    this.width = width;
};


ProgressBar.prototype.getWidth = function () {
    "use strict";
    return this.width;
};

function ComposedProgressBar() {
    "use strict";
    this.progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    ProgressBar.call(this);
}


var composedProgressBar = new ComposedProgressBar();

composedProgressBar.setHeight(300);
console.log(composedProgressBar.getHeight());
composedProgressBar.setWidth(300);
console.log(composedProgressBar.getWidth());
```

Comment: so to sum it up, you want a composition that would behave just like inheritance. Why not inherit in this case ?

Comment: @VincentPiel: That's a good question. One reason might be to support [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance).

Comment: you can either quite easily add two (or more) prototype objects, or chain the prototypes to get multiple inheritance.

Comment: I want a composed object containing a progress bar and other things. Due to the way the progress bar has been implemented, subclassing it causes some problems. I expect I'll just implement it using passthrough functions, as it'll be easier for others to read and understand the code. Since I read how to access privileged methods, I've been wondering if it would be easy to do something similar with public methods. 

Partly this is just an exercise in composition in Javascript, as I've been experiencing the bane of long inheritance chains and the problems they can cause.

Comment: What do you need those "passThrough" functions for in the first place? Can't you just omit them and always call the actual functions on the `.progressBar` property directly?

Comment: The passthrough functions would be required to set/get progressBar values from an instance of composedProgressBar. So, from outside of the ComposedProgressBar class.

Comment: @VincentPiel: I can't picture that. I thought that every object has a single prototype, which has a single prototype, and so on. Is that not true? (Are you sure you're correctly understanding the term "multiple inheritance"?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could write something like:

```
for (var methodName in ProgressBar.prototype) {
    if (typeof ProgressBar.prototype[methodName] === 'function'
            && ProgressBar.prototype[methodName]
                   !== ComposedProgressBar.prototype[methodName]) {
        ComposedProgressBar.prototype[methodName] = (function (methodName) {
            return function () {
                return this.progressBar[methodName]
                           .apply(this.progressBar, arguments);
            };
        })(methodName);
    }
}
```

(Naturally this would only create delegates for methods that already exist in `ProgressBar.prototype`: it wouldn't detect any methods added later, and wouldn't support the ad-hoc method-ing of `apply`.)

Comment: Thanks. That does create delegates in a way that would be usable to me, but for some reason the setter doesn't set the value at all.